# How do I fill a downward slope in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I was trying to make an upward slope level and used Channel on it, but that turned it into a downward slope. How do I 'fill' the downward slope so that it becomes level with the ground?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can <kbd>b</kbd>uild-<kbd>C</kbd>onstruct a <kbd>f</kbd>loor over it, or a <kbd>w</kbd>all on the level below. In the future, if you want to get rid of upward ramps, <kbd>d</kbd>esignate them with <kbd>z</kbd>Remove upward ramps/stairs, rather than channeling them.

Comment: Alternately, you can Construct a Wall on the tile just below it.